# for (a?) good reason: difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrases, articles, indefinite-articles

Google search provides us with cca 50 million results for the article version and 28 million for the no-article variant. Is there any actual difference?

Comment: I'd say that the article-less version is far more formal. It also allows more than one reason to be added more comfortably than the articled version.

Comment: Count vs mass noun. Not sure about the significance. @Edwin's comment seems apropos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a slight difference in connotation.  "A good reason" implies  "a *single* good reason," it implies that there is  or is not a compelling reason so there's the sense of a particular reason.

"For good reason" implies that reason is a bulk quantity, like sugar.  There's some measure of reason.